# Sharing Bitmap via Android Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, intentfilter

In my android app, I have a bitmap (say b) and a button. Now when I click on the button, I want to share the bitmap. I am making use of the below code inside my `onClick()` to achieve this :-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, b);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Share"));
```

I was expecting a list of all application which are able to handle this intent but I get nothing. There is no list of apps nor is there any error in android studio. My application just get hanged for sometime and then quits.

I have checked the bitmap and it is fine (its not null).

Where am I a going wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to attach a Bitmap when launching ACTION\_SEND intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160593/how-to-attach-a-bitmap-when-launching-action-send-intent)

Answer (score 83):

I found 2 variants of the solution. Both involve saving Bitmap to storage, but the image will not appear in the gallery.

## First variant:

Saving to external storage

- but to private folder of the app.
- for API <= 18 it requires permission, for newer it does not.

### 1. Setting permissions

Add into AndroidManifest.xml before  tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

### 2. Saving method:

```
 /**
 * Saves the image as PNG to the app's private external storage folder.
 * @param image Bitmap to save.
 * @return Uri of the saved file or null
 */
private Uri saveImageExternal(Bitmap image) {
    //TODO - Should be processed in another thread
    Uri uri = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "to-share.png");
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        stream.close();
        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException while trying to write file for sharing: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return uri;
}
```

### 3. Checking storage accesibility

External storage might not be accessible, so you should check it before trying to save: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

```
/**
 * Checks if the external storage is writable.
 * @return true if storage is writable, false otherwise
 */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

## Second variant

Saving to cacheDir using FileProvider. It does not require any permissions.

### 1. Setup FileProvider in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <application>
        ...
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### 2. Add path to the res/xml/file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>
    </paths>
</resources>
```

### 3. Saving method:

```
 /**
 * Saves the image as PNG to the app's cache directory.
 * @param image Bitmap to save.
 * @return Uri of the saved file or null
 */
private Uri saveImage(Bitmap image) {
    //TODO - Should be processed in another thread
    File imagesFolder = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
    Uri uri = null;
    try {
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(imagesFolder, "shared_image.png");

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.mydomain.fileprovider", file);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException while trying to write file for sharing: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return uri;
}
```

More info about file provider - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

*Compressing and saving can be time-consuming, therefore this should be done in a different thread*

## Actual sharing

```
/**
 * Shares the PNG image from Uri.
 * @param uri Uri of image to share.
 */
private void shareImageUri(Uri uri){
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution I think , step-by-step detailed explanation. Sharing with images stored in cache is better if security is of concern. I had missed a step of adding xml and provider so it was not working but finally followed the steps and it works now.

Comment: Best solution over internet for sharing over email.

Comment: The new package name for the FileProvider since Android X is: `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Very clear and detailed step by step.

Answer (score 28):

As CommonsWare stated you need to get the URI to the bitmap and pass that as your Extra.

```
String bitmapPath = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,"title", null);
Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);
...
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri );
```

Comment: It works but also stores image. so, image is also showing in gallary. How can i avoid saving image or showing this into gallary.

Comment: @JaydipKalkani I need this too, but maybe we cant.

Answer (score 21):

Finally, I got the solution:

**Step 1 :**
Share Intent handling Block. This will Pop Up your window with list of Applications in you phone

```java
public void share_bitMap_to_Apps() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    i.setType("image/*");
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    /*compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();*/

    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(mContext, getBitmapFromView(relative_me_other)));
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "My Profile ..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Step 2 :**
Converting your view to Bitmap

```java
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    // Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    // Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    // Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        // has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        // does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    // return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

**Step 3 :**
To get The URI from Bitmap Image

```java
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: don't forget to require android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Any solution to do it without write external storage?

Comment: `stream` and `bytes` are discarded. Remove these. `insertImage` compresses to JPEG.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is the best solution for even other use cases, basically like taking a screen shot of the exact thing or view you want as is.

Answer (score 11):

```
ImageButton capture_share = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.share);
capture_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {

    String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,"title", null);
    Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/png");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
  }
});
```

Comment: Add some description to answer for clear understanding. @lalit Baghel

Answer (score 6):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM):

> A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the data being sent.

`b`, therefore, is not supposed to be a `Bitmap`, but rather a `Uri` pointing to a `Bitmap`, served by a `ContentProvider`. For example, you could write the `Bitmap` to a file, then use `FileProvider` to serve it.

Answer (score 3):

A solution in Kotlin with a timestamp in the image's filename:

```
val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
val imagePath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
    context?.contentResolver,
    bitmap,
    "img_$timeStamp",
    null
)
val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
    type = "image/*"
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imagePath))
}
context?.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null))
```

Comment: `insertImage` deprecated in API level 29.

_inserting of images should be performed using MediaColumns#IS_PENDING, which offers richer control over lifecycle._

(which will also be deprecated soon enough lol)

Answer (score 1):

After spending a lot of time on this:

**Check if permissions are given. Then:**

**Step 1: Create ImageView of the image you want to in the activity and then convert it itno bitmap**

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

//save the image now:
saveImage(bitmap);
//share it
send();
```

**Step 2: Store the image in internal folder:**

```
private static void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    Log.i("Directory", "==" + myDir);
    myDir.mkdirs();

    String fname = "Image-test" + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Step 3: Send the saved image:**

```
public void send() {
    try {
        File myFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/saved_images/Image-test.jpg");
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = myFile.getName().substring(myFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
        sharingIntent.setType(type);
        sharingIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.fromFile(myFile));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Now after sending you can delete the saved image if you don't want it in your storage. Check other link to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void sharePalette(Bitmap bitmap) {

 String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "palette", "share palette");
    Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/png");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
}
```

Comment: insertImage deprecated

Answer (score 0):

As `Images.Media.insertImage`  is **deprecated**, the best way use `FileProvider` as @APA & @kjs566 mentioned in Java and in **Kotlin** :(I checked until **SDK 31**)

```
 val imageName = "/image.jpg"
        try {
            File(this.cacheDir, "images").deleteRecursively() 
            val cachePath = File(this.cacheDir, "images")
            cachePath.mkdirs() 
            val stream = FileOutputStream("$cachePath$imageName")
            bitmap.compress(
                Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,90,stream) 
            stream.close()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {}

        // SHARE
        val imagePath = File(this.cacheDir, "images")
        val newFile = File(imagePath, imageName)
        val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.src.noveinway.fileprovider", newFile)
        if (contentUri != null) {
            val shareIntent = Intent()
            shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) 
            shareIntent.type ="image/jpeg" 
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri)
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a file for share")
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose app"))
        }
```