# Which Environment.SpecialFolder.XXX will give me Context.getFilesDir()?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to access a folder in which I can save temporary files and write there a file and where I don't need permission to write to the folder.

I currently use:

```
string targetBaseDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal,
    Environment.SpecialFolderOption.Create
    );
```

This gives me a private directory for which I need no permissions which is the directory that corresponds to `Context.getFilesDir()`, however as I don't need the file to exist permanently it would be cleaner if I could save them in the directory that corresponds to `Context.getFilesDir()`. What do I have to write instead of `.Personal` to get the directory?

Comment: Check @[kjs566](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5479478/kjs566) 's answer [Sharing bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222918/sharing-bitmap-via-android-intent) Its for sharing for you can modify some code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` via `Xamarin.Essentials` in your .NetStd library to obtain what is the "getFilesDir()" location on Android.

#### Example:

```
var appData = Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
```

`appData` equals `/data/user/0/com.sushihangover.FormsTestSuite/files`

And the Android `FilesDir`:

```
Log.Debug("SO", FilesDir.ToString() );
```

Equals `/data/user/0/com.sushihangover.FormsTestSuite/files`

> access a folder in which I can save temporary files

In that case use the Cache dir:

```
var cacheDir = Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.CacheDirectory;
```

`cacheDir` would equal: `/data/user/0/com.sushihangover.FormsTestSuite/cache

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/

Answer (score 0):

Both `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` and `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` will give you the path of `Context.getFilesDir()`.

However, if you want to save **small** temporary files, you can make use of the cache directory `Context.getCacheDir()`.

There is no special folder enum for the cache directory though. You'll have to get the path from the current context `Context.CacheDir.Path`, or from `Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.CacheDirectory` if you use `Xamarin.Essentials` API.

Read more:
[File access with Xamarin.Android with SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#working-with-internal-storage)
[Writing cache file in internal storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteCacheFileInternal)
[File system helpers in Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?tabs=android)