# How to take a screenshot of a GridLayout and then share it

Tags: java, android, grid-layout

I have bingo app where there is a  GridLayout showing all the numbers done, left.
I want to take a screenshot of it and then share it.
I have tried many posibillities and tried to do many thing, but none of them worked

```
case R.id.share:
      //the answer should be here
```

the name of the GridLayout is gridLayout

if you need any other code of explanation, please tell me

Comment: It's quite long process ... You need to take the view and convert it to bitmap ... and get the image check these link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801116/converting-a-view-to-bitmap-without-displaying-it-in-android ...go through some other links related to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that we want to take the screenshot when a button is clicked, the code will look like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
       saveBitmap(bitmap);
   }
});
```

Calling getDrawingCache(); will return the bitmap representing the view or null if cache is disabled, that’s why setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); should be set to true prior invoking  getDrawingCache().

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
   View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
   rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}
```

This code is from [this](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/taking-a-screenshot-of-current-activity-in-android/) website
The website also contains the code to save the screenshot taken.

Also question is possible duplicate of [how to take a screen shot on a button click can anyone provide a android code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624133/how-to-take-a-screen-shot-on-a-button-click-can-anyone-provide-a-android-code/38157486)

Comment: then how to share it?

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.logicchip.com/share-image-without-saving/ and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222918/sharing-bitmap-via-android-intent